# Is there an FPGA implementation of Donald Knuth's MMIX?

Tags: fpga, softcore

Does anyone know of an FPGA soft-core implementation of Donald Knuth's [MMIX](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/mmix.html)? My google search only found old discussions of people who knew people who were working on an FPGA implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google threw this up:

http://repo.or.cz/w/fpgammix.git

Answer (score 1):

A simulation running on a PC might be more useful than a softcore, especially for testing algorithms.